# MLFlow properly installed in conda env but can't use it

Tags: conda, mlflow

Once the conda env is activated, `which mlflow` returns the correct path.
However, when running `mlflow server`, it doesn't seem to find it.

[image]

Did anyone meet this problem before?

Comment: want to mention that `mlflow run` works fine but not `mlflow ui` for example

Comment: what version of mlflow?

Comment: MLflow version: 1.8

Comment: See the gunicorn path is pointing to a locally installed package, not in conda env. Check what python you have: `which python`, `which python3`. Or may be anbother python setting/env variable is interfering. It's definitely a wrong python issue